# Spring get ServletContext and provide it as a Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, javabeans

> I want to get the ServletContext in a Java Spring Webproject and use
>   it to get the absolute path of my web-application project. I'm still a
>   beginner in JavaEE and Spring, so maybe I've got some concepts wrong.
>   In the java class, in which I want to use the ServletContext, I got
>   only an empty object when using   @Autowired ServletContext context;
>   But in my RestConfiguartion class, which extends the
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, I got the ServletContext and I'm able
>   to use it in a Java Bean, with the return type of ServletContext. But I
>   have no idea, how I can use the Bean in another class to get the
>   ServletContext, is this possible?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ ServiceConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.rest", "de.security" })
public class RestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  ServletContext context;    

  @Bean
  public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    System.out.println("*** Context path: *** " + context.getRealPath("/"));
    return context;
  }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

In other bean annotated classes too. You'll get the same context.
Because of it, you don't need to specify:

```
@Bean
  public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    System.out.println("*** Context path: *** " + context.getRealPath("/"));
    return context;
  }}
```

For example (any class in directories, specified in your annotation `@ComponentScan`):

```
@Bean
class X {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your help I've solved it, by adding the package of my target class to @ComponentScan, declared my target class @Component and inserted the Bean I used before. Theses are the resulting code snippets:

```
...
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.rest", "de.security", "de.targetPackage" })
public class RestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...



@Component
public class targetClass {

  private static String absoluteServletContextPath;

  @Autowired
  ServletContext context;

  @Bean
  public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    absoluteServletContextPath = context.getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println(absoluteServletContextPath);
    return context;
  }

  @Override
  public void myMethod {

        absoluteServletContextPath = absoluteServletContextPath.replaceAll("webapp\\\\", "")
          .replaceAll("\\\\", "/");}}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what are those specified here `{ "de.rest", "de.security", "de.targetPackage" }` ? Are they the other classes under the packages being scanned? And do they have the actual servlet which is being injected in the `targetClass`?