# How to read war-file manifest in its jar-dependency?

Tags: java, spring, jar, war, manifest

How do I read the `war`-file manifest property in its `jar`-dependency?

UPD: servlets are not used here (it's spring-bean initialization code).

Comment: Are you asking how to read the manifest of a .war file from a class which resides in one of the .war file’s WEB-INF/lib/*.jar files?

Comment: @VGR
Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a .war file’s purpose is to handle servlets, I assume all of your code is called from servlets, or from a technology built on servlets, like JSP, JSF, or even Spring.

Call the current request’s [getServletContext() method](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext--), and use the [getResource](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [getResourceAsStream](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) method of ServletContext.  Those methods work just like the same methods of java.lang.Class, only they look in the .war file itself before searching the web application’s classpath for a matching path.

For example:

```
public Optional<Manifest> getWarManifest(ServletRequest request)
throws IOException {

    InputStream manifest =
        request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(
            "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

    if (manifest == null) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    try (InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(manifest)) {
        return Optional.of(new Manifest(stream));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Since you want to read the manifest when preparing a Spring bean, it appears [you can autowire a ServletContext object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269496/spring-get-servletcontext-and-provide-it-as-a-bean):

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBean createMyBean(@Autowired ServletContext context)
    throws IOException {

        Optional<Manifest> manifest;

        InputStream source =
            context.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

        if (source == null) {
            manifest = Optional.empty();
        } else {
            try (InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(source)) {
                manifest = Optional.of(new Manifest(stream));
            }
        }

        return new MyBean(manifest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for reply. But servlets are not used here. I am trying to get a manifest in the initialization code of spring-bean (starting spring-context). Updated the question.

Comment: @slider Updated answer.  I haven’t tried this approach, though.

Comment: It works correctly. This is what was required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be an alternative approach... If you can change the build configuration of your WAR file, then you can simply add all build properties into a different file in an accessible location. For example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/classes/maven.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After that, you can access all needed information from it without bothering with the Manifest file.